# gcc: Why export LD_LIBRARY_PATH needed when -L flag is specified?

Tags: c, gcc

I am learning linking in C and came to know that we have to add our working directory to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

But why is this required if I already tell the linker to use the path through `-L` flag?

Comment: Sometimes the user puts the libraries in a different place than you thought

Comment: If you specify it on the command line, then you shouldn't have to add it to the environment variable.

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` isn't needed, and can easily be avoided. In fact it could often be seen as [harmful](https://gms.tf/ld_library_path-considered-harmful.html). The workaround is to set the runtime path in the application when linking, using the `-rpath` linker-specific option (if using a driver program like `gcc` then use `-Wl,-rpath,/path/to/library`, I think systems like CMake will add it automatically)).

Comment: -L tells the linker where to find a library at link time. At run time the library can be in a totally different place since LD... is talking about dynamic linkage

Comment: @pm100 `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` affects link time as well.